# How to handle error from MVC controller on JqGrid inline editing

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
     onSelectRow: function(id) {
                         if (id && id !== lastsel<%= count %>) {
                             $j(gridName).restoreRow(lastsel<%= count %>);                               
                             $j(gridName).editRow(id, true);                                 
                             lastsel<%= count %> = id;
                         }                       
                     }
```

How do I handle the error thrown from MVC controller function to the Jqgrid inline edit.

```
    Function Edit(ByVal collection As FormCollection) As ActionResult
       Return Content("false")
    End Function
```

The document says `saveRow (rowid, succesfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc, onerrorfunc)`  . How do I call the onSuccessHandler and onError Handler.

Will pareciate if someone can provide a dummy code.

Answer (score 1):

```
saveRow (rowid, onSuccessHandler , url, extraparam, aftersavefunc, onErrorHandler);

onSuccessHandler = function(data) {
}

onErrorHandler = function(data) {
}
```